# Are LEEDs certifications available for homes?

Tags: leed-certification, home

I've seen various levels of [LEEDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leadership_in_Energy_and_Environmental_Design) certifications on public buildings but never for a private home.

Are such certifications available for a home and if so, how would I go about finding a building who would be able to meet the goals put forth in LEEDs?  Would trying to get a LEEDs certification on a new home mean I would have to use an architect and if so, how would you find a residential architect with experience in this area?

Comment: The wiki article you link specifically mentions a "LEED for Homes" category. The requirements may not be impossible to meet without a LEED focused architect, though with the range and scope of requirements, it would probably be your best bet. Finding an architect with LEED experience would probably be best accomplished by meeting with available architects and asking them up front about the possibility of LEED certification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would want to refer back to the overall governing body on this one for the best response: http://new.usgbc.org/leed/certification/homes. USGBC developed the LEED standard and this page outlines all of the costs and considerations for getting a home certified. Yes, you will definitely need to have someone do the verification. However, I believe that they don't have to be an architect to be LEED certified. I know one or two people in my area (central California, US) that are LEED Professionals who are not full architects.

The same professionals would also be your best bet for locating any houses that have been certified. I would try contacting some Architecture firms and asking about LEED professionals. Another good bet, in my experience, is to look for activities/gatherings with an environmental leaning and asking about it there. I have found "Green Drinks" events to be a good nexus for this if you have one in your area: http://www.greendrinks.org/